# How to upload images from a folder in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working in an application in which user wants uploads all images in a folder by selecting folder path as in case of desktop applications.
In asp.net user can uploads multiple images by following code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" multiple="true" runat="server" />
```

But this code not fulfills our requirement i want to select the folder only and the images in it should be uploaded from it.

How to uploads images by giving folder path in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Just using javascript you won't be able to access the client's disk due to browser's security restrictions. You would need to use java or flash to achieve this.